# openldap ACL for namingContext

Tags: ldap, acl

I am trying to block access to our openldap's namingContexts. The openldap server hosts directories for several DNs, and we don not want anyone from being able to identify which DNs are being hosted by the server.

I understand that namingContext is an operational attribute and part of the rootDSE. Obviously, ldap clients need access to some entries of the rootDSE in order to operate properly.

On the other hand, it looks like rootDSE entries are also subject to ACL.

The question is whether the namingContext attributes are required to be publicly readable in order for a client to connect to the server, or whether the namingContext attributes can be restricted. If the later, what would be a suitable ACL for this? We use openldap.

Answer (score 1):

The following access control:

```
access to attrs="namingContexts" by * none
```

denies access to `namingContexts`.